# Guava cycle how is it achieved

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to figure out how Guava is creating the iterator that cycles infinitely over itself but I cannot figure it out.

```
public static <T> Iterable<T> cycle(final Iterable<T> iterable) {
checkNotNull(iterable);
return new FluentIterable<T>() {
  @Override
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return Iterators.cycle(iterable);
  }
  @Override public String toString() {
    return iterable.toString() + " (cycled)";
  }
};
}

public static <T> Iterator<T> cycle(final Iterable<T> iterable) {
checkNotNull(iterable);
return new Iterator<T>() {
  Iterator<T> iterator = emptyIterator();
  Iterator<T> removeFrom;

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
      iterator = iterable.iterator();
    }
    return iterator.hasNext();
  }
  @Override
  public T next() {
    if (!hasNext()) {
      throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    removeFrom = iterator;
    return iterator.next();
  }
  @Override
  public void remove() {
    checkRemove(removeFrom != null);
    removeFrom.remove();
    removeFrom = null;
  }
};
```

}

However it does not show how exactly this is achieved. I am missing something probably.

Comment: `if (!iterator.hasNext()) {iterator = iterable.iterator();}` seems to be quite clear, when old iterator has no more elements get new one and start again.

Comment: Well basically it calls `iterator()` on the original iterator every time it gets to the end...

Comment: @Pshemo it is clear... I need to take a break. I did not see it at all. Add it as an answer so as to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of code

```
if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
  iterator = iterable.iterator();
}
```

checks if old iterator has no more elements. When this is true it simply gets new iterator which will let us start again.